# How to format my jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have managed to setup a background image on hover of another element using this great forum! As I am new to jQuery and javascript, I am struggling to format adding additional effects on hover. e.g. I don't just want to use an append on the background-image I also want to do a background-size:cover; append and a transition: all 0.33s ease. How would I go about adding this to the current syntax?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Preload
    $('<img/>').hide().attr('src', '../img/background-experience.jpg').load(function(){
        $('body').append($(this));
    });

    $('.btn').hover(function() {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url("../img/background-experience.jpg")');
    }, function() {
        $('body').css('background', '');
    });
});
```

EDIT: FOLLOWING HELP FROM NOEL

Added using custom class which may be a better solution now having issues with the transition this is my scss code.

```
body {
  background: $black;
  color: $white;
  font-family: $default-font;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: all 0.33s ease;
}

.my-custom-class {
  background-image:url('https://yt3.ggpht.com/-V92UP8yaNyQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/zOYDMx8Qk3c/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: So you want to add more css styles.. That's what are you looking for?

Comment: hey Sam--not sure what's happening here, but can you do a fiddle so that I can see the transition problem you're having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put everything in a css class that you can add to your body on hover of the button.  This requires two things: (1) defining the css rule; then (2) adding, removing this on hover.

Below is a sample code to show this in action. Hope this helps!

```js
$('.btn').hover(function() {
        $('body').addClass('my-custom-class');
    }, function() {
        $('body').removeClass('my-custom-class');
    });
```

```css
.my-custom-class {
  background-image:url('https://yt3.ggpht.com/-V92UP8yaNyQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/zOYDMx8Qk3c/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg');
  
  background-size:cover;
}

body {
  background-image:url('https://www.petdrugsonline.co.uk/images/page-headers/cats-master-header');
  background-size:cover;
transition: all 0.33s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">My button</button>
```

Comment: great that helped @SamDucker.  It'd be highly appreciated if you could accept my answer? I need the points haha

Comment: For whatever reason the transition won't work though. I've added the css code, to the original post and I will do :)

Comment: thanks! the transition rule has to be applied to the body, not the custom-class. Otherwise, when you hover out, the animation will be abrupt (since the transition ease is only applied to the custom-class, which is activated on hover)

Comment: Yeah that's how I did it, I've also just tried instead of applying it to the body. Applying it to a .hero class and changing the javascript respectively. Transition still isn't applying.

Comment: Fixed, just had to move the order of the classes around a bit.

Comment: good for you! knowing your way around Jquery+CSS is a powerful combination in executing great front-end designs.  good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can add more styles as below,

```
$('body').css({'background-image':'url("../img/background-experience.jpg")','transition':'all 0.33s ease','background-size':'cover'});
```

Comment: Hi I tried this, didn't work sadly. Then modified it to this which also didn't work. The only example where it is doing anything is the original post not in the two edits we just came up with

    $('body').css({'background-image: url("../img/background-experience.jpg")','transition: all 0.33s ease','background-size:cover'});

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add css3 transition property for the image you want to show transition when hover. Then you must add css on hover for setting background size cover.

For more information about transition css3 property [w3shools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)